# Specify underlying type of an enum in C

Tags: c, enums

C++11 lets you explicitly specify the underlying type of an `enum`, e.g.

```
enum Status : uint8_t
{
    OK = 0,
    BAD = 1,
};
```

Does any version of C provide a similar feature?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039534/forcing-the-size-of-an-enumd-field-in-a-structure#comment73170767_43039534

Comment: @PSkocik enum constants are `int`, enum type is implementation-defined integer type (may be other than `int`).

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for the correction. I assume it can't be larger, than int, though, given that "The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int." and "The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration."